# How to run Java EE application on CentOS

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, centos

I created an application with EJB and JSF.

I'd like to deploy my application to the web, so I got a dedicated server from hostgator. On this server I installed CentOS 6.7, Java 7 and JBoss AS 7.1.

I addition to that I have my own domain name.

How can I deploy my application to this server and how I can make this application reachable via my domain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is information directly from JBoss:

```
[standalone@localhost:9999 /] deploy ~/Desktop/test-application.war
'test-application.war' deployed successfully.

[standalone@localhost:9999 /] undeploy test-application.war
Successfully undeployed test-application.war.
```

You can also deploy manually:

> Basic workflows: All examples assume variable $AS points to the root
>   of the JBoss AS 7 distribution.
>
> A) Add new zipped content and deploy it:
>
> ```
> cp target/example.war $AS/standalone/deployments/
> (Manual mode only) touch $AS/standalone/deployments/example.war.dodeploy
> ```
>
> B) Add new unzipped content and deploy it:
>
> ```
> cp -r target/example.war/ $AS/standalone/deployments
> (Manual mode only) touch $AS/standalone/deployments/example.war.dodeploy
> ```
>
> C) Undeploy currently deployed content:
>
> ```
> rm $AS/standalone/deployments/example.war.deployed
> ```
>
> D) Auto-deploy mode only: Undeploy currently deployed content:
>
> ```
> rm $AS/standalone/deployments/example.war
> ```
>
> E) Replace currently deployed zipped content with a new version and
>   deploy it:
>
> ```
> cp target/example.war/ $AS/standalone/deployments
> (Manual mode only) touch $AS/standalone/deployments/example.war.dodeploy
> ```
>
> F) Manual mode only: Replace currently deployed unzipped content with
>   a new version and deploy it:
>
> ```
> rm $AS/standalone/deployments/example.war.deployed
> wait for $AS/standalone/deployments/example.war.undeployed file to appear
> cp -r target/example.war/ $AS/standalone/deployments
> touch $AS/standalone/deployments/example.war.dodeploy
> ```
>
> G) Auto-deploy mode only: Replace currently deployed unzipped content
>   with a new version and deploy it:
>
> ```
> touch $AS/standalone/deployments/example.war.skipdeploy
> cp -r target/example.war/ $AS/standalone/deployments
> rm $AS/standalone/deployments/example.war.skipdeploy
> ```
>
> H) Manual mode only: Live replace portions of currently deployed
>   unzipped content without redeploying:
>
> ```
> cp -r target/example.war/foo.html $AS/standalone/deployments/example.war
> ```
>
> I) Auto-deploy mode only: Live replace portions of currently deployed
>   unzipped content without redeploying:
>
> ```
> touch $AS/standalone/deployments/example.war.skipdeploy
> cp -r target/example.war/foo.html $AS/standalone/deployments/example.war
> ```
>
> J) Manual or auto-deploy mode: Redeploy currently deployed content
>   (i.e. bounce it with no content change):
>
> ```
> touch $AS/standalone/deployments/example.war.dodeploy
> ```
>
> K) Auto-deploy mode only: Redeploy currently deployed content (i.e.
>   bounce it with no content change):
>
> ```
> touch $AS/standalone/deployments/example.war
> ```

Read more at https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Application+deployment?_sscc=t