# How to deploy a java ee Application to CentOS

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, centos, centos7

i made a java ee App with Glassfish Server and it is working fine in my localhost but now i need to deploy the App to Centos so that everyone could use it but i dont know how to proceed or where to start ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Java EE application on CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414385/how-to-run-java-ee-application-on-centos)

Comment: i read the post but didint understand how i could apply it to my case ! im new to IT so deployement is like a monster for me haha !